# How to display form variables based on variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, controls

I have a list of variable names, lets say:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("size");
    list.Add("width");
    list.Add("name");
    list.Add("zip");
```

and i have text controls with those exact names, is there a way to loop through the list and only display what the value of the text control that i am asking for, like lets say something like this:

```
foreach (string txtctl in list) 
    {
        Response.Write(Request.Form[txtctl]);
    }
```

When i run this code the value just displays blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered the attributes in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations?  If you created a class with members and applied the DisplayAttribute, your output code could then use those attributes to pump out the right labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string str = "";
foreach (string item in list)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)Form.FindControl(item);
    if (txt != null)
    {
        str += item+":"+ txt.Text+"<br>";
    }
}
Response.Write(str);
```